# How to retry socket server creation with spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-boot, spring-integration

The following is my socket server configuration. I want to define a fallback/failover port.

How can I retry the socket bean creation (eg with a fallback port) if the current port is already in use?

If the failover port is also already in use: how can I retry the socket creation as long until it succeeds (eg für 5 mins)?

```
    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean f = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        f.setType("server");
        f.setPort(port); //I want to retry and switch that port
        f.setUsingNio(true);
        f.setSingleUse(false);
        f.setDeserializer(deserializer);
        f.setSerializer(serializer);
        return f;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway server(
            TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory,
            MessageChannel serverChannel) throws Exception {
        TcpInboundGateway g = new TcpInboundGateway();
        g.setConnectionFactory(factory.getObject());
        g.setRequestChannel(serverChannel);
        return g;
    }
```

Comment: So having a random port assigned can be useful for you?

Comment: No, I want to have a main port and a failover port. Only those 2 are valid. I want to retry those two until one succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides a utility class called `SocketUtils` which exposes a handful of methods for working with sockets.

The one useful to you can be [SocketUtils.html#findAvailableTcpPort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.html#findAvailableTcpPort-int-int-) which takes to input parameters, `minPort` and `maxPort`, and will return you an available tcp port in the a range *[minPort, maxPort]*. You can call this method for your ports, and if they are consecutive you can just use the one that the method returns. In the case the ports are not consecutive you will need to match the returned port against yours.

```
@Bean
public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory(LengthHeaderDeserializer deserializer) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> waitForSocket(port)).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    ....
}

private void waitForSocket(int port) {
    do {
        try {
            SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(port, port);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                return;
            }
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so spring tries opening a socket on that port, and directly closes it thereafter. To test the availability. I could probably use that to wait on a free port before creating the `TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean`.

Comment: I just added an example how I solved it using `SocketUtils`, just for completeness.

Comment: @membersound great.

Answer (score 0):

It is more reliable to listen on port 0 so that the operating system chooses an available port.

Comment: While this might be true in general, I have to use a fixed port number that I have no control of. So there is no chance for me to use a different / system chosen one.